# Edited --- Normalizing Constant Z in Markov Random Fields

Tags: markov-process, markov-random-field

I want to implement [this](https://vdocuments.site/an-efficient-mrf-embedded-level-set-method-for-image-segmentation.html) paper in MATLAB. This is the formula:
$$ P(L)=\prod_{s \in S} \frac{1}{Z} exp(- \sum_{c \in N^w(s)}V_c(L_s))  $$
However, I confused to compute $Z$ (normalizing constant) as explained the paper Equation 15 in page 3. I've been searching to implement $Z$ with [this MRF definition](https://ermongroup.github.io/cs228-notes/representation/undirected/), but it has different formula. This is the formula:
$$ p(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)= \frac{1}{Z}\prod_{c \in C} \phi_c(x_c)$$
As explained in that link, $Z$ can be computed by:
$$ Z=\sum_{x_1,x_2,...,x_n}\prod_{c \in C} \phi_c(x_c) $$
Can anyone help me to compute $Z$ in $P(L)$?

Comment: could you provide a bit more context to each link? SE policy in general is that sufficient context should be given that if the target site moves and the link breaks then the text still conveys some meaning.

Comment: The first link is paper with title "An Efficient MRF Embedded Level Set Method for
Image Segmentation". Then the next link is a theory about Markov Random Field (MRF).

Comment: You state things like 'different formula', '1/Z is outside the product', 'this link is so different'. You should show the formulas in your question so each reader can easily compare them side by side. This then retains the relevant information in the questions should the links rot. If you're not familiar with MathJax notation a reviewer can tidy up formulas.

Comment: I've been giving the formula in the question.

Comment: Perhaps you should try for a question that is more self-contained.. That way, someone may actually attempt to answer it, rather than just vote to close the question.

Comment: Therefore, should I focus on someone who can answer this question personally?